# AuthenticationException: Error connecting with login URI

Tags: java, exception, google-docs, google-docs-api

Consider the following error related to a token issue in Google Docs.

How can this be resolved?

> com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error connecting with login URI

Comment: Add a code sample and the exact stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Go over the code where you are handling the token this error can occur if the wrong token is provided.